# Thrust CUDA allocating char * to device_vector of objects

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I am having trouble making a deep copy of a host_vector to device_vector. I think that I am having an issue modifying the value of an element stored in a device_vector. You can find a compilable version at the bottom but the code in question is the following (i put stars on the rows that trigger the segmentation fault):

```
thrust::host_vector<CharArr> hostToSort(size);
            thrust::host_vector<long long> hostToSortRow(size);
            for(int i =0; i < size; i++){
                CharArr sortRow;
                sortRow.value = arrayToSort[i];
                sortRow.length = strlen(arrayToSort[i]);
                hostToSort[i] = sortRow;
                hostToSortRow[i] = arrayToSortRow[i];
            }
            thrust::device_vector<CharArr> deviceArrayToSort =hostToSort;
            //thrust::copy(hostToSort.begin(),hostToSort.end(),deviceArrayToSort.begin());
//           = ;// (arrayToSort,arrayToSort + size);
            thrust::device_vector<long long> deviceArrayToSortRow = hostToSortRow;//(arrayToSortRow,arrayToSortRow + size);

           // thrust::sort(deviceArrayToSort.begin(),deviceArrayToSort.end());
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){

                char * hostString = hostToSort[i].value;
                int sizeString = strlen(hostString);
                char * deviceString = 0;

                CharArr * deviceCharArr = (&deviceArrayToSort[i]).get();
                cudaMalloc((void **) deviceString,sizeString);
                cudaMemcpy(deviceString,hostString,sizeString,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
            ****    deviceCharArr->length = sizeString;
            ****    deviceCharArr->value = deviceString;
            }
```

What happens is that when we arrive at the actual assignment
    deviceCharArr->value = deviceString
It throws a Segmentation Fault error. I am very new to CUDA and apologize if there is an obvious answer but I have not been able to find many examples of people allocating char * on devices.

Complete Compilable version is here

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>

#include <thrust/reduce.h>


typedef struct{

    char * value;
    int length;
} CharArr;


struct CharArrayCmp{
    __host__ __device__
      bool operator()(const CharArr & o1, const CharArr & o2) {
          return this->compare(o1.value,o1.length,o2.value,o2.length);
      }

    __host__ __device__ bool compare (const char * src, int lenSrc, const char * dst, int lenDest)
    {
        int end;
        if(lenSrc > lenDest){
            end = lenDest;
        }else{
            end = lenSrc;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < end; i++){
            if(src[i] > dst[i]){
                return false;
            }else if(src[i] < dst[i]){
                return true;
            }
        }
        if(lenSrc >= lenDest){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
};


void sortCharArrayHost(char ** arrayToSort, long long * arrayToSortRow,long long size){
    std::cout <<"about to start LongIndex" <<std::endl;

            thrust::host_vector<CharArr> hostToSort(size);
            thrust::host_vector<long long> hostToSortRow(size);
            for(int i =0; i < size; i++){
                CharArr sortRow;
                sortRow.value = arrayToSort[i];
                sortRow.length = strlen(arrayToSort[i]);
                hostToSort[i] = sortRow;
                hostToSortRow[i] = arrayToSortRow[i];
            }
            /*thrust::device_vector<CharArr> deviceArrayToSort =hostToSort;
            //thrust::copy(hostToSort.begin(),hostToSort.end(),deviceArrayToSort.begin());
//           = ;// (arrayToSort,arrayToSort + size);
            thrust::device_vector<long long> deviceArrayToSortRow = hostToSortRow;//(arrayToSortRow,arrayToSortRow + size);

           // thrust::sort(deviceArrayToSort.begin(),deviceArrayToSort.end());
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                char * deviceString = 0;
                char * hostString = hostToSort[i].value;
                int size = strlen(hostString)*sizeof(char);
                int cudaStatus;
                CharArr * deviceCharArr = (&deviceArrayToSort[i]).get();
                cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void **) deviceString,size);
                cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(deviceString,hostString,size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

                (&deviceArrayToSort[i]).get()->value = "";
            }
*/
//          thrust::sort_by_key(deviceArrayToSort.begin(),deviceArrayToSort.end(),deviceArrayToSortRow.begin(),CharArrayCmp());
            thrust::sort_by_key(hostToSort.begin(),hostToSort.end(),hostToSortRow.begin(),CharArrayCmp());

            //copy the contents back into our original array to sort now sorted
          //  hostToSort = deviceArrayToSort;
            for(int i =0; i < size; i++){
                arrayToSort[i] = hostToSort[i].value;
            }
//          thrust::copy(deviceArrayToSortRow.begin(),deviceArrayToSortRow.end(),arrayToSortRow);
            thrust::copy(hostToSortRow.begin(),hostToSortRow.end(),arrayToSortRow);


}
void sortCharArrayDevice(char ** arrayToSort, long long * arrayToSortRow,long long size){
    std::cout <<"about to start LongIndex" <<std::endl;

            thrust::host_vector<CharArr> hostToSort(size);
            thrust::host_vector<long long> hostToSortRow(size);
            for(int i =0; i < size; i++){
                CharArr sortRow;
                sortRow.value = arrayToSort[i];
                sortRow.length = strlen(arrayToSort[i]);
                hostToSort[i] = sortRow;
                hostToSortRow[i] = arrayToSortRow[i];
            }
            thrust::device_vector<CharArr> deviceArrayToSort =hostToSort;
            //thrust::copy(hostToSort.begin(),hostToSort.end(),deviceArrayToSort.begin());
//           = ;// (arrayToSort,arrayToSort + size);
            thrust::device_vector<long long> deviceArrayToSortRow = hostToSortRow;//(arrayToSortRow,arrayToSortRow + size);

           // thrust::sort(deviceArrayToSort.begin(),deviceArrayToSort.end());
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){

                char * hostString = hostToSort[i].value;
                int sizeString = strlen(hostString);
                char * deviceString = 0;

                CharArr * deviceCharArr = (&deviceArrayToSort[i]).get();
                cudaMalloc((void **) deviceString,sizeString);
                cudaMemcpy(deviceString,hostString,sizeString,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
                deviceCharArr->length = sizeString;
                deviceCharArr->value = deviceString;
            }

            thrust::sort_by_key(deviceArrayToSort.begin(),deviceArrayToSort.end(),deviceArrayToSortRow.begin(),CharArrayCmp());
        //copy the contents back into our original array to sort now sorted
            for(int i =0; i < size; i++){
                arrayToSort[i] = (&deviceArrayToSort[i]).get()->value;
            }
            thrust::copy(deviceArrayToSortRow.begin(),deviceArrayToSortRow.end(),arrayToSortRow);



}
int main()
{
    char ** charArr = new char*[10];

    charArr[0] = "zyxw";
    charArr[1] = "abcd";
    charArr[2] = "defg";
    charArr[3] = "werd";
    charArr[4] = "aasd";
    charArr[5] = "zwedew";
    charArr[6] = "asde";
    charArr[7] = "rurt";
    charArr[8] = "ntddwe";
    charArr[9] = "erbfde";

    long long * rows = new long long[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10;i++ ){
        rows[i] = i;
    }

    sortCharArrayHost(charArr,rows,10);

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        std::cout<<"Row is "<<rows[i]<<" String is "<<charArr[i]<<std::endl;

    }


    charArr[0] = "zyxw";
    charArr[1] = "abcd";
    charArr[2] = "defg";
    charArr[3] = "werd";
    charArr[4] = "aasd";
    charArr[5] = "zwedew";
    charArr[6] = "asde";
    charArr[7] = "rurt";
    charArr[8] = "ntddwe";
    charArr[9] = "erbfde";


    for(int i = 0; i < 10;i++ ){
        rows[i] = i;
    }
    sortCharArrayDevice(charArr,rows,10);

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            std::cout<<"Row is "<<rows[i]<<" String is "<<charArr[i]<<std::endl;

        }

}
```

Comment: By `CharArr * deviceCharArr = (&deviceArrayToSort[i]).get();` you are assigning a host-side pointer (`deviceCharArra`) to a device memory location (`(&deviceArrayToSort[i]).get()`). Then the operation `deviceCharArr->length = sizeString;` is being performed on the host, involving a memory location meaningless for the host.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As JackOLantern has already pointed out, this is not acceptable:

```
// this creates an allocation on the device
thrust::device_vector<CharArr> deviceArrayToSort =hostToSort;
// this takes the (device) address an element and assigns it to a pointer variable
CharArr * deviceCharArr = (&deviceArrayToSort[i]).get();
// this then dereferences a device pointer in host code which is illegal
deviceCharArr->length = sizeString;
```

In CUDA you are not allowed to dereference a device pointer in host code or vice-versa.

It seems you have the following data sets:

1. The strings to be sorted
2. An array of string "handles" consisting of `CharArr` objects each containing pointer to start of string and length
3. An array of string indices (i.e. 0, 1, 2, ...)

You want to sort 2, and 3 above, based on 1.  Thrust "likes" to have everything in one or 2 vectors, if possible. Let's try the following:

1. concatenate all strings together into a single `char` vector.
2. mark the *start index* of each string in another `int` vector.  The difference in successive start indices will constitute the length of each string.  We'll combine the start and the length of each string into a thrust::tuple for use in the comparator, by using a zip_iterator
3. sort the "tuple array" (i.e. sort index and length at the same time) using the desired comparison functor.  Any necessary rearrangement of other data can be accomplished using the reordered index vector.
4. If you want a re-ordered string index also (i.e. 0, 1, 2, ...) you can create that vector easily enough and add it as a third element to the tuple to be sorted.

Note that the above approach entirely avoids the use of pointers, which as you've seen can be troublesome to manage between host and device copies of the same data.

Here's a fully worked example:

```
$ cat t439.cu
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>

#define NUM_STRINGS 10



struct stringCmp{

  const char * strings;

  stringCmp(char * _strings) : strings(_strings) {}

template<typename myTuple>
    __host__ __device__
      bool operator()(const myTuple & o1, const myTuple & o2) {
        int idxSrc = thrust::get<0>(o1);
        int lenSrc = thrust::get<1>(o1);
        int idxDst = thrust::get<0>(o2);
        int lenDst = thrust::get<1>(o2);
        int end;
        if(lenSrc > lenDst){
            end = lenDst;
        }else{
            end = lenSrc;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < end; i++){
            if(strings[idxSrc+i] > strings[idxDst+i]){
                return false;
            }else if(strings[idxSrc+i] < strings[idxDst+i]){
                return true;
            }
        }
        if(lenSrc >= lenDst){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
};

void sortCharArrayDevice(char ** arr, int *rows, int num_str){

    thrust::host_vector<char> h_strings;
    thrust::host_vector<int>  h_st_idx(num_str);
    thrust::host_vector<int>  h_len(num_str);
    thrust::host_vector<int>  h_rows(num_str);
    // concatenate strings
    // assume no zero length strings
    h_st_idx[0] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_str; i++){
      int sidx = 0;
      while (arr[i][sidx] != '\0'){
        h_strings.push_back(arr[i][sidx]);
        sidx++;}
      h_len[i] = sidx;
      if (i < num_str-1) h_st_idx[i+1] = h_st_idx[i] + sidx;
      h_rows[i] = rows[i];
      }
    // copy data to device
    thrust::device_vector<char> d_strings = h_strings;
    thrust::device_vector<int>  d_st_idx = h_st_idx;
    thrust::device_vector<int>  d_len = h_len;
    thrust::device_vector<int>  d_rows = h_rows;
    // sort on device
    thrust::sort(thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(d_st_idx.begin(), d_len.begin(), d_rows.begin())), thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(d_st_idx.end(), d_len.end(), d_rows.end())), stringCmp(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_strings.data())));
    thrust::copy(d_rows.begin(), d_rows.end(), rows);
}


int main()
{
    char ** charArr = new char*[NUM_STRINGS];

    charArr[0] = "zyxw";
    charArr[1] = "abcd";
    charArr[2] = "defg";
    charArr[3] = "werd";
    charArr[4] = "aasd";
    charArr[5] = "zwedew";
    charArr[6] = "asde";
    charArr[7] = "rurt";
    charArr[8] = "ntddwe";
    charArr[9] = "erbfde";

    int * rows = new int[NUM_STRINGS];
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_STRINGS;i++ ){
        rows[i] = i;
    }

    sortCharArrayDevice(charArr,rows,NUM_STRINGS);

        for(int i = 0; i < NUM_STRINGS; i++){
            std::cout<<"Row is "<<rows[i]<<" String is "<<charArr[rows[i]]<<std::endl;

        }

}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 -o t439 t439.cu
$ ./t439
Row is 4 String is aasd
Row is 1 String is abcd
Row is 6 String is asde
Row is 2 String is defg
Row is 9 String is erbfde
Row is 8 String is ntddwe
Row is 7 String is rurt
Row is 3 String is werd
Row is 5 String is zwedew
Row is 0 String is zyxw
$
```

Comment: Robert you are the most helpful person I have ever encountered on a forum. Thanks so much this is exactly what I needed help understanding. This all makes sense to me now. Thank you for the advice on thrust and what works better in sorting. I am going to spend more time reading up on the cuda docs its obvious I do not know enough.